# Best way to handle and deploy XQuery stored procedures?

Tags: xquery, exist-db

Is there a tool for deploying things into exist? if I've got a bundle of, say, schemas and XQuery stored procedures? Is there a way of, say, bundling those into a zip or tar file and uploading them or deploying them into eXist?

Alternatively what is the best way of storing these things in a version controlled way (in a git repo, say) and deploying them to the eXist server? Ideally, it'd be nice to be able to have a simple script in a scripting language so you can simply call "deploy.py" or whatever and it'd take everything from the repository and load it into the XML database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EXpath packaging system](http://expath.org/modules/pkg/) specifies a format for generating a ZIP file with XQuery procedures (and other content) and deploying it into multiple XQuery databases.

See the [specification](http://expath.org/spec/pkg). You should be able to use the Python [zipfile module](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) to generate these if you're inclined to use Python (though personally, I do so from a makefile).

Unfortunately, the process for checking currently installed package versions to upgrade if necessary is not standardized; I have a solution for BaseX, but nothing for eXist immediately at hand. However, eXist's implementation is [well-documented](http://demo.exist-db.org/exist/repo/repo.xml), and you should have little trouble working with it.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I wrote a little Ruby script that just uploaded them all, and noted in my documentation that the version in Git is the canonical version of any XQuery. ;-)